# Understanding error: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python

I'm just working on an example to help me learn how OOP works in Python. Here's the class I'm working with:

```
class account(object):
    def __init__(self,holder,number,balance,credit_line=1500):
        self.holder=holder
        self.number=number
        self.balance=balance
        self.credit_line=credit_line

    def deposit(self,amount):
        self.balance+=amount

    def withdraw(self,amount):
        if (self.balance-amount < -self.credit_line):
            #coverage insufficient
            return False
        else:
            self.balance-=amount
            return True

    def balance(self):
        return self.balance

    def transfer(self,target,amount):
        if (self.balance-amount < -self.credit_line):
            #coverage insufficient
            return False
        else:
            self.balance-=amount
            target.balance+=amount
            return True
```

And here's the driver program I'm using to test it with:

```
import account

john=account.account("John Doe","12345","1000.00")
res=john.balance()
print "%r" %res
john.deposit(1500)
res=john.balance()
print "%r" %res
```

I get an error when I try to run this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "banker.py", line 4, in <module>
    res=john.balance()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Anyone have any idea why this is?

Comment: I'd highly recommend using distinct names, you currently have 2 different things named `balance`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though `self.balance` is defined as a method in your class, it is replaced with a string during `__init__` when `self.blance=balance`. Therefore when you call `john.balance()` in this case where `balance` is the string `"1000.00"`, it returns the pretty helpful error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`.

Recommendations:

1. Use different names for the method and for the attribute.
2. It looks like balance is a number. Why pass it as a string?
3. The `balance` method currently just returns the value. Really there's no need for a method in the current example. But if you want to develop it to do further stuff on each call, of course this is the way to go.

Comment: Oh okay, this was the source of my problems. I don't know why I put 1000.00 in quotes when I instantiated the object. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You're masking your object's attributes.

```
self.balance=balance
```

and

```
def balance(self):
```

Python does not distinguish between `self.balance` the number and `self.balance` the function. Whatever is assigned last is the one that sticks. Give each attribute a unique name.

Comment: self.balance will call the attribute whereas self.balance() will call the function.  as tigerhawk mentioned, you should rename your function and use some verbage like set_balance(self)

Comment: "self.balance will call the attribute whereas self.balance() will call the function" - the attribute and the function are one and the same, until it's masked by the new value on initialization. When it's defined, `self.balance` _is_ an attribute. It happens to be a function, so it can be called. `self.balance` would only call the function if it was an `@property`. When the object is instantiated, the reference that used to point to the function will now point to something else, and the function will no longer have a reference to it.

Comment: detail that i didn't realize.  you're absolutely right

Answer (score 0):

You can't give the same name to a method and an attribute of your class. You don't need the `balance()` method and in general python don't use the getter and setter methods to access attributes. `Class_name.attribute_name` will return the value of your attribute

```
def balance(self):
        return self.balance
```

Answer (score 0):

You have overwritten your function  `balance` with your attribute  `balance`. You should rename  your attribute to for example `self._balance` .